# iOS - synching audio between devices with millisecond accuracy

Tags: ios, audio, time, synchronize

I need to synch audio in networked devices with millisecond accuracy. I've hacked together something that works quite well, but is'nt perfectly reliable :

1)Server device sends an rpc with a timeSinceClick param

2)client device launches the same click offsetted according to the time the rpc spent in transit,

3)System.Diagnostics.StopWatch checks periodicaly on all connected devices to make sure playback hasn't deviated too much from absolute time and corrects if necessary

Are there any more elegant ways to do this? Also, my way of doing it requires manual synching if non iOS devices are added to the mix : latency divergences make it very hard to automate...

I'm all eyes!

Cheers,

Gregzo

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to synchronize multiple devices on the same machine with millisecond accuracy, so if you are able to do this on multiple machines I would say you are doing well. I'm not familiar enough with iOS to the steps you describe, but I can tell you how I would approach this in cross-platform way. Maybe your approach amounts to the same thing.

1. one machine (the "master") would send a UDP packet with to all other machines.
2. all other machines would reply as quickly as possible.
3. the time it takes to receive the reply, divided by two, would be (approximately) the time it takes to get a packet from one machine to another. (this would have to be validated. maybe it takes much longer to process and send a packet? probably not)
4. after repeating steps 1-3, ignoring any extreme values and averaging the remaining results, you know about how long it takes to get a message from one machine to another.
5. now "sync" UDP packets can be sent from the main machine to the "slave" machines. The sync packets will include delay information so that when the save machine receive the packets, they know they were sent x milliseconds ago. Several sync packets may need to be sent in case the network delays or drops some of them.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer ! Alas it is quite close to what I am doing already... I was wondering if there was a more absolute way of doing things. For example, how does airport express manage to airplay through 2 different speakers in perfect sync? Or maybe there's a way to get ultra-precise atomic time somehow, and bypass the sync problem altogether?

Comment: I'm not familiar with airport express. It's possible that, since it's hardware, they can sync with each other first more accurately. I think the accuracy of this technique is really predicated on the the reliability and repeatability of the timing measurements. You may want to, for example, repeat them several times and use the lowest values, since anything above the lowest value is error.

Comment: Don't think about atomic clocks. It doesn't matter how accurate your clock it, it matters how closely they are synched to each other. Any clock drift between the two machines will be small compared to any offset in network latency (unless you are planning to run this continuously for many many hours -- like a week).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Using the lowest value is a very good idea, will do. I'd upvote if I could! And about atomic clocks: of course you're right. If you don't mind, I won't accept your answer yet as there might be more input on the subject.

Comment: Okay. Good luck! Do come back and report on what you find.